# Saving windows command prompt history to a file

Tags: windows-server-2008, ms-dos

Is it possible to save DOS command prompt history to a file?

I'm going to work in sqlplus and would like to save all commands that were used and executed in a log file.

Example, I would like to save all DOS commads executed in a DOS session:

```
C:\> sqlplus /nolog
sql> connect / as sysdba
sql> select * from v$version;
etc, etc
```

I tried to do before:
doskey /history >> C:\commands.log

But it does not record anything. I'm in a Windows Server 2008 64 bits.

Comment: Try a different directory, that you create like `C:\temp`.  UAC can kill that redirection silently when saving to a "system" directory, including root of C.

Comment: dos key logs what happens in the shell, now what happens within programs that are launched.

Answer (score 3):

Start Powershell, use the [transcript](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff687007.aspx) functionality.

> Start-transcript Initializes a transcript fi le and then creates a
>   record of all subsequent actions in the PowerShell session. Use the
>   following syntax:
>   Start-Transcript [[-path] FilePath] [-force] [-noClobber] [-append]
>
> Stop-transcript Stops recording actions in the session and finalizes
>   the transcript. Use the following syntax:
>   Stop-Transcript